# How to interpret a logistic regression model with negative coefficients of varying magnitudes and odds ratios <1?

Tags: logistic, likelihood, odds-ratio

I'm doing logistic regression where `X` has four factors (1-4) and `Y` has two factors (0-1). I did:

```r
model=glm(formula=y~x,family=binomial(link=logit),data=data) #x=='1' is reference level
summary(model)
```

I get:

```
Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                -1.6740     0.3632  -4.608 4.06e-06 ***
2                          -1.0916     0.5000  -2.183    0.029 *  
3                          -1.9369     1.0766  -1.799    0.072 .  
4                          -16.8921  1058.1118  -0.016    0.987
```

Then for my odds ratios, I get:

```
                          ORs 2.5 %       97.5 %
(Intercept)              0.19  0.09 3.600000e-01
2                        0.34  0.12 9.100000e-01
3                        0.14  0.01 8.200000e-01
4                        0.00    NA 1.057042e+21
```

I'm most interested in variable 2 and I'm confused how I would interpret its odds ratio. I would think that an `OR<1` would mean a lesser likelihood of outcome `Y=1`, but seeing how the log-likelihood coefficient for the intercept/variable 1 is less than variable 2. I'm confused if the OR for var2 would still be considered 'lower' than var1.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The interpretation of the (exponentiated) intercept in logistic regression is not odds ratio, but rather simply the odds. The exponentiated coefficient estimate of Variable 2 retains the odds ratio interpretation, and yes Var2 decreases the log-odds than when Var1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a desired result in mind (var2 lowers the probability of $Y=1$ than var1) and are perplexed by the numbers. The intercept $\beta_0$ in logistic regression should be interpreted carefully since $e^{\beta_0}$ is **not** an odds ratio. Observe this:
$$
\begin{align}
\beta_0 &= \mathrm{logit}(P(Y=1\mid \text{var2}=0, \text{var3}=0))\\
e^{\beta_0} &= \frac{P(Y=1\mid \text{var2}=0, \text{var3}=0)}{1-P(Y=1\mid \text{var2}=0, \text{var3}=0)}.
\end{align}
$$
But the slopes are different:
$$
\begin{align}
\beta_1 &= \mathrm{logit}(P(Y=1\mid \text{var2}=1,\text{var3}=0)) - \mathrm{logit}(P(Y=1\mid \text{var2}=0,\text{var3}=0))\\
&= \mathrm{logit}(P(Y=1\mid \text{var2}=1,\text{var3}=0)) - \beta_0\\
e^{\beta_1} &= \frac{P(Y=1\mid \text{var2}=1,\text{var3}=0)/P(Y=0\mid \text{var2}=1,\text{var3}=0)}{P(Y=1\mid \text{var2}=0,\text{var3}=0)/P(Y=0\mid \text{var2}=0,\text{var3}=0)}.
\end{align}
$$
The interpretation of slopes is always relative to the baseline (i.e., the intercept).

Comment: Thank you for both comments - super helpful!